# ng build --prod Angular 8 CSS Rendering Issue compared to when running ng serve

Tags: angular

I have an angular 8 application that I have developed and the CSS for all components are in each component's corresponding.

When I run ng serve all CSS renders correctly where I want it to.

However anytime I run ng build --prod to prepare files for hosting after deploying those files to my url, every single component is used in by 10%-20% this throws off all my divs and styling and causes a terrible user experience.

I ran ng build --prod --extractCss=false then deployed those files and the same issue happened.

Is there anything anyone can suggest to either get the ng build --prod command to function like ng serve with certain flags or a path issue with css that I can try to fix.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: just ran "ng build --prod --aot=false --output-hashing=media --sourceMap=true --extract-css=false --buildOptimizer=false"

And that still didn't fix the issue. It's almost like the CSS is just zooming in by 10%, which is enough to throw off all my divs, padding etc.

EXAMPLE: On a page that has no scroll feature when run using ng serve, after running the ng buld --prod command from above including all the flags, the page now has the ability scroll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Angular-cli's github wiki v2+, these are the most common ways to initiate a dev and production build

````
ng build --target=production --environment=prod
ng build --prod --env=prod
ng build --prod

# Dev and so are these
ng build --target=development --environment=dev
ng build --dev --env=dev
ng build --dev
ng build
There are different default flags that will affect --dev vs --prod builds.

Flag                 --dev      --prod
--aot                false      true
--environment        dev        prod
--output-hashing     media      all
--sourcemaps         true       false
--extract-css        false      true```
````

Comment: When I run my dev localhost where everything works I am only typing "ng serve". When I run "ng build --prod" all the css is thrown off. 

Do you know which of the flags you listed above could b causeing my problem? I have tried several different time with each one and it still isn't working

Comment: ng build --prod --aot=false --output-hashing=media --sourceMap=true --extract-css=false --buildOptimizer=false

^^^ ended up being the command that fixed the issue then I also had to "zoom out" a little in my google chrome browser for a few of the issues. Guessing that there are a few parts of the css that need to be dynamic